# How to dynamically load a managed (.Net) DLL in unmanaged code?

Tags: dll, unmanaged, managed

How to dynamically load a managed (.Net) DLL in unmanaged code?

I'm creating a plugin system in C++ that gets injected into an application and I would like to be able to write C# plugins.

I've searched a bit but could only find COM loading (with #import), but I don't know how to do that at runtime, if it's possible.

The C# DLL (Plugin) could call functions in the C++ DLL (Plugin Manager).

I would prefer a solution that doesn't require me to compile the C++ DLL with /clr.

Comment: You can't load a managed assembly without bootstrapping the CLR.  Using COM will do this for you automatically.  The other option is to load and initialize the CLR yourself.  Which requires writing COM code but it is pretty boilerplate.  Google "corbindtoruntimeex".

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/45ba1348-52e3-44cb-bdc3-935584f46ce7 and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2006/08/07/691467.aspx might help you to host CLR inside your native c++ app.

Comment: Hans, your comment should be the answer.

Comment: Yes, I would've accepted it as an answer. Hurry and add it. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

> I would prefer a solution that doesn't require me to compile the C++ DLL with /clr.

At some level, to use a C# DLL, you'll need to bootstrap the CLR.  Using /clr has a huge advantage - you can provide a truly managed API for the C# plugin to work against.

Your main other options are to either use COM, and provide a COM based API.  This will work fine from C# as well as other languages, and take care of loading the CLR for you.  The only other API is to [self-host the CLR using the hosting APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx).  This provides you the most control, but is definitely a fair amount of extra work.

Comment: Gonna use /clr then... Thanks.

Comment: I ended up hosting the CLR in my DLL.